# Calculate time taken to reply an answer in forum

Tags: java

Hi I have a group project at my uni. Me and my group members are required to create a website.
We already done that, now this year we learn about Java programming language. And my lecturer give us another task to upgrade our website from static to dynamic using Java, especially using JSP (JavaServer Pages).

I am responsible to create a statistical report for our website for this new task. So far I am able to find how to calculate mean, sum and median from the internet especially from this forum. But **I am unable to find how to calculate time taken for admin to answer a question from the user based on a String ArrayList.**

So can someone help me with this? I'm really new with this Java, any help will be appreciated.

And I'm sorry for my grammar, English is not my main language. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the String ArrayList contain? Does it contain the time taken for the admin to answer a question, or what exactly?

Comment: You have to forgive me first , if I'm misleading you or if I give a wrong statement about String ArrayList. This String ArrayList contains the time taken for the admin to answer the question. I'm sorry if my explanation is not that clear.

Comment: It's alright no problem. But if the list already contains the time taken for the admin to answer the question, why do you want to calculate it if it's already present in a list? Sorry if I'm not fully understanding the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help and it's okay man. What if the String ArrayList doesn't contain anything but it dependant on the user input? Is it possible to do it? Just like in Python? You know using the input things? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a thread to keep time:

```
public class KeepingTime
{
    private volatile int timeTaken;
    private Thread timekeeper;

    public KeepingTime()
    {
        timekeeper = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        timeTaken++;
                        if(Thread.interrupted())
                            return;
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }    //end run
        }); //end thread
        timekeeper.start();
    }    //end constructor

    public void stop()
    {
        timekeeper.interrupt();
    }

    public int timeTaken()
    {
        return timeTaken;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
for(String question : questions)
{
    KeepingTime timer = new KeepingTime();
    //ask the question
    //wait until it is answered
    timer.stop();
    int timeTaken = timer.timeTaken();
}
```

Note that I'm not using Thread.stop() since it is deprecated. This might be inconsistent if you're running a lot of threads.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will ask my lecturer about this code. Enjoy the rest of your day.